# Varnish grace-mode not working

Tags: varnish

referring to https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Saving_a_request.html#exercise-grace
I tried to integrate the most basic configuration for grace mode described on the page.

But it´s not working completely. Result of the test should be:

1. "With this exercise, you should see that as long as the content is within the regular TTL, there is no difference."
2. "Once the TTL expires, the first client that asks for the content should be stuck for 15 seconds, while the second client should get the graced copy."

Point 1 is working correctly, but point 2 doesn´t.

The first client who requests the page after the timeout has to wait for the result. Thats ok. But in my case, against the documentation, all other clients also have to wait for the request . It seems that varnish doesn´t recognize that the request is already being processed by another client.

Anybody an idea whats wrong here. I´m using v3.0.5 of varnish.

Here is my configuration:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}
sub vcl_recv {
        set req.grace = 10s;
}

sub vcl_fetch {
       set beresp.grace = 10s;
}
```

And thats the test cgi script

```
#! /bin/sh
sleep 15
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo "Cache-control: max-age=20"
echo
echo "Hello world"
date
```

Comment: Make sure that your browser doesn't contain any cookies, maybe because some session cookie was created varnish started passing all requests to backend

Comment: omg that solved the problem. Futhermore tests with gatling showed me that the behaviour is correct. Thanks. P.S. feel free to create an answer, I´ll mark it as solution.

Comment: great, when I have time I'll add a detailed answer to explain this.

Comment: And this should definitely be part of the varnish wiki. They describe to open another browser window to see behaviour. A hint for deactivating cookies there would be great and would have saved hours.

Comment: actually it's mentioned, but not exactly under this example